# How to change the color of specific bars in a bar chart?

Tags: python, bar-chart

I'm currently creating a bar chart on python that shows data related to air quality stations. However I've been facing quite a problem to change the colour of specific bars. I would like to have specific stations with one color (tomato for example) and the rest with other color (grey).

[Bar chart at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqML.png)

```
data_AirQ = pd.concat(list, axis=1)   

columnspm10 = [i for i in data_AirQ.columns if i.endswith('pm10')]
pm10_1h = data_AirQ[columnspm10]


daily = lambda x: x.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
h24 = pm10_1h.groupby(daily, axis=0)
pm10_24h = h24.mean()[h24.count() >= 18]


yearly = lambda x: x.replace(month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
y = pm10_24h.groupby(yearly, axis=0)
annualmean = y.mean()[y.count() >= 0.75*365]
annualmean.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)
annualmean = annualmean.transpose()

# PM10 exceedences
exc = pm10_24h[pm10_24h > 45.0]
n_exc = exc.groupby(yearly, axis=0).count()[y.count() >= 0.75*365]                                  
n_exc.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)
n_exc = n_exc.transpose()


#figure 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))

# annual mean
axs = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax = annualmean.plot(kind='bar', ax=axs, color = 'midnightblue', legend=None)
plt.axhline(y=5, xmin=0, xmax=1, linestyle=':', linewidth=1, color = 'k')
plt.xticks([],[])    
ax.set_ylabel('annual mean concentration of PM10 ($\mu g.m^{-3}$)')
```

Comment: I hope [this](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/3-control-color-of-barplots) might help.

Comment: It helped clarify some doubts but i still can't plot the bars i want with a different color